# Elasticbeanstalk clear uploaded directory

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This is different from the `/tmp` directory

Uploaded directory is where all uploaded files are copied and the path looks something like `/var/folders/8w/t4x8j_kd3bgf_h9wnkn5zgtr0000gn/T/`

Question, is there a process that cleans up this directory? I'm getting health warnings because of low disk space issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, posting it for those for are running into same problem.

Linux doesn't clean up uploaded directory automatically, solved it by using deleting it manually using server side script.